# How to join data from one model into another based on a specific field?

Tags: mongoose, database-design, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have 3 different show times for Movie-A in the Shows model and want to store all these IDs for Movie-A in the shows array on the Movie model, only if the title in the Movies document is also Movie-A.

Show model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ShowSchema = new Schema({
  date: {
    type: String,
  },
  startTime: {
    type: String,
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Show", ShowSchema);
```

Movies model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const MovieSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
  },
  year: {
    type: String,
  },
  rated: {
    type: String,
  },
  released: {
    type: String,
  },
  runtime: {
    type: String,
  },
  genre: {
    type: String,
  },
  director: {
    type: String,
  },
  writer: {
    type: String,
  },
  actors: {
    type: String,
  },
  plot: {
    type: String,
  },
  country: {
    type: String,
  },
  awards: {
    type: String,
  },
  poster: {
    type: String,
  },
  imdbRating: {
    type: String,
  },
  imdbPoster: {
    type: String,
  },
  shows: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Show",
    },
  ],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Movie", MovieSchema);
```

Sample data :

```
 {
    title: "Inception",
    year: "2010",
    rated: "PG-13",
    released: "16 Jul 2010",
    runtime: "148 min",
    genre: "Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi",
    director: "Christopher Nolan",
    writer: "Christopher Nolan",
    actors: "Leonardo DiCaprio, Joseph Gordon-Levitt, Elliot Page",
    plot: "Dom Cobb is a skilled thief, the absolute best in the dangerous art of extraction, stealing valuable secrets from deep within the subconscious during the dream state, when the mind is at its most vulnerable. Cobb's rare ability has made him a coveted player in this treacherous new world of corporate espionage, but it has also made him an international fugitive and cost him everything he has ever loved. Now Cobb is being offered a chance at redemption. One last job could give him his life back but only if he can accomplish the impossible, inception. Instead of the perfect heist, Cobb and his team of specialists have to pull off the reverse: their task is not to steal an idea, but to plant one. If they succeed, it could be the perfect crime. But no amount of careful planning or expertise can prepare the team for the dangerous enemy that seems to predict their every move. An enemy that only Cobb could have seen coming.",
    country: "United States, United Kingdom",
    awards: "Won 4 Oscars. 159 wins & 220 nominations total",
    poster:
      "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjAxMzY3NjcxNF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNTI5OTM0Mw@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
    imdbRating: "8.8",
    imdbID: "tt1375666",
  },
```

```
{
    date: "12th June",
    startTime: "18.30",
    title: "Inception",
  },
  {
    date: "12th June",
    startTime: "20.30",
    title: "Inception",
  },
  {
    date: "12th June",
    startTime: "22.30",
    title: "Inception",
  },
```

I would like Inception stored with the ID's as reference to the Movie model. I need to match based on title on both models. I can only get all show times to be stored in the shows array instead of the times for a movie.